# Transform .csv into 3 columns and a row

Tags: shell, text-processing, scripting, csv-simple

Sample Input:

```
id,Product1,Product2,Product3,Product4
1,0.1,0.3,0.8,0.7
2,0.6,0.7,0.5,0.9
```

I need output as :

```
id,productname,product_val
1,Product1,0.1
1,Product2,0.3
1,Product3,0.8
1,Product4,0.7
2,Product1,0.6
2.Product2,0.7
3,Product3,0.5
```

I had tried

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
         NR>1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print sn[i] "," $i;}' filename.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

except for the new headings, which you can easily add, this does it:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
     NR>1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "," sn[i] "," $i }' filename.csv
```